# Can I use XAML Designer in a CMake-controlled project?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, xaml-designer

I have a CMake project which I've [opened in Visual Studio 2022 Professional as a directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170), using a `CMakePresets.txt` to make some build presets.

I have a `dotnet new wpf` project added to this CMake project with `include_external_msproject(....csproj TYPE "FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC")`.

I want to be able to design the `.xaml` files using the WYSIWYG XAML Designer tool in Visual Studio, but don't have that option in this directory view (which is mandated for the CMakePresets integration).

Is this possible?

Workaround for now is to configure CMake, and then open the `.sln` with Visual Studio. I can then find the project in the list and use the designer. It's just clunky to have to re-open the same project a different way.

Comment: This is the first i heard of cmake, but I know visual studio and xaml editing. In visual studio, do you not have a solution explorer based list of files? If you can click a xaml file in solution explorer i'd expect you to be able to get it open in the designer and editor.

Comment: @Andy cmake is a program that *generates* solution files that can be fed into vs's build tools. Recently, Microsoft started providing first-party support for CMake-based workflows in Visual Studio (see the first link in my question). This support for CMake provides an alternative view into your source code, which largely hides the existence of solutions and projects from the developer, treating them as opaque build artifacts. While in this view, the XML Designer does not appear.